# How to install Xcode 11.3 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6?

Tags: macos, xcode11, xcode11.3, xcode11.4

Currently I am using **Xcode 10.1** on **macOS High Sierra 10.13.6**, on a Early 2011 MacBook Pro with 4GB RAM.

Problem is that I am unable to upgrade to macOS Catalina. Is it possible to install Xcode 11.3 in the macOS High Sierra? Or is there any other safe solution for installation of macOS Catalina in my unsupported Early 2011 MacBook Pro and then install Xcode 11.3?

Please suggest a well tested and safe solution.

Comment: Usually the word "unsupported" means that nothing really is well tested and safe solution...

Comment: Oh, and this is the wrong place. https://superuser.com is most likely better suited for this

Comment: Read up on the Mohave patch available here. http://dosdude1.com/mojave/. You can run Xcode 11.3 (though not 11.4) with the high versions of Mohave such as 10.14.6. If you have an old computer, you don't want to go Catalina as it will brick any 32bit software.

Answer (score 0):

Your model of Mac, i.e. Early 2011 MacBook Pro can't be upgraded past macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 using any official means, i.e. macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 is the highest supported macOS release for your model of Mac.

<sub>Source: [Mactracker app for macOS and iOS](https://mactracker.ca)</sub>

The last release of Xcode supported on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 is Xcode 10.1.

<sub>Source: [Xcode - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#10.x_series)</sub>

So, officially speaking, your model of Mac cannot run macOS Catalina and by extension Xcode 11.x.

There is no officially supported solution.

Xcode 11.3 is supported on macOS Mojave 10.14.4 or later. So, your best recourse would be to be get a Mac that can run the said release of macOS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nimesh Actually I am already aware about all those facts which you've mentioned above, but I am willing to have some solution coz Currently I am in the area where I've no access to outer world to have new Mac Machine